# Raspberry Pi as Download Machine?

Tags: linux, download, updates, raspberry-pi, home-server

I live in a country where internet speed is fairly low.

I was interested if it is possible to cut down on my power bill by using the raspberry pi as a download machine (i know it can be done for torrents) but I am also thinking about games and game patches from services such as origin or steam.

So would it be possible to somehow configure the RPi to take over all downloads, even from third party software?

-Hugs

Comment: Any power savings you would gain by doing this would be lost because of the lack of processing power.  You would also have the entire problem of Steam being unable to even run on an ARM distro of Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to have a Linux system automatically download things.

Command line tools such as `wget` and `curl` are one method, as are the plethora of bittorrent applications for Linux.  You can even do a remote X session and get Iceweasel running if you have to use a browser.

The thing you want to download will need to work with an available Linux tool.  There's no easy way to make something that isn't aware of the Pi's existence download something "batch-style" on another machine's behalf.

So if an application requires its own client to download patches, unless you or someone is willing to reverse engineer that client, you don't have a way to tell the Pi to do that for you without the client.

I'm not sure if Steam patches can be downloaded manually or without the client.  If they can be, then you can tell the Raspberry Pi to do that.